# How to sort a table column by clicking on the header in SWT?

Tags: java, sorting, swt

I have an SWT table and I need to add sorting functionality to it...Most Columns contain numerical values, but some do contain letters and dates. Here is how the table is created and columns are added:

```
  protected void createTable ( Composite panel, String colnames[], Rectangle location )
  {
    TableColumn column;
    boolean checkflag = scalefactor > 0;
    int buttonwidth, properties = SWT.BORDER|SWT.FULL_SELECTION;
    if (checkflag) properties |= SWT.CHECK;
    if (colwidth == 0) colwidth = 80;
    dataTable = new Table(panel,properties);
    dataTable.setLinesVisible(true);
    dataTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
    if (checkflag)
    {
        Button button = new Button(dataTable,SWT.CHECK);
        button.pack();
        buttonwidth = button.getSize().x+4;
        button.dispose();
        column = new TableColumn(dataTable,SWT.CENTER);
        column.setWidth(buttonwidth);
        column.setResizable(true);
    }
    for ( int n = 0; n < colnames.length; n++ )
    {
      column = new TableColumn(dataTable,SWT.CENTER);
      column.setWidth(colwidth);
      column.setText(colnames[n]);
    }
```

I need to sort each created column simply by clicking the header. Is it possible?

Comment: Look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508493/swt-table-sorting-by-clicking-the-column-header

Comment: Rakesh - thank you but i already saw that..Does not really fit my case since i have a LARGE number of columns which values and names are pulled from a database...So i dont really know which are strings and which are ints etc

Comment: @user3116665 You should really think about using a `TableViewer` instead.